# Login Page in PHP

Tags: php, authentication

I created a login page in php named as index.php. Now when the user logs in it redirects to mypage.php. The login works fine. But also mypage.php gets open when I type the url of mypage.php even without login. I want the user must logged in to see mypage.php and incase if he changes the url in browser then an error message should be triggered. What to do?

1.localhost/index.php
2.localhost/mypage.php

Comment: Come on. This is a simple thing that has been covered hundreds of times. Learn to search.

Comment: @Kalpesh Mehta give you a good answer. But you should consider using a better pattern, like this very simple one : http://www.codercaste.com/2010/01/16/php-design-patterns-how-to-properly-create-a-website-index-page/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a login to work correctly, your "secure" page (I use that term relatively because nothing is truly secure) needs to have some sort of validation conditional. In other words you need to have some way of determining if the user is logged in.

A simple way to do this in PHP is to set a `session` variable when you process the user's credentials. For example:

When the user successfully logs in set a session variable like so:

```
$_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = true;
```

Then on the mypage.php check to see if the variable is set:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['isLoggedIn']) || $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] != true) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

Please also note, it is imperative if you are using sessions that you have `session_start();` as the first line of all of your files. This allows `$_SESSION` variables that were set on a separate page to be able to be read on the current page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

In index.php, once the user gets logged in successfully, set an session. like `$_SESSION['login'] = true;` before redirect. If invalid login, use `$_SESSION['login'] = false;` Don't forget to start the session on the top of the page. `session_start();`

In mypage.php, check if that session is set or not. If not set, throw error, else show the page.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] == true) {
   echo 'You are welcome'; 
} else {
   echo 'redirecting to login page';
   header('Location: index.php');
   exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How are you storing the state of being 'logged in'?

You'll need to have your mypage.php check a variable that has been set by the index.php's successful login process.

Can you paste your code here and I can take a look

Comment: "You'll need to have your mypage.php check a variable that has been set by the index.php's successful login process." Does that mean I have to implement session for that?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't get back to you sooner. @War10ck has explained it the way I would have done.